# Submit Button Limit For a User

Tags: php, cookies, submit

How can I set a Clicking Submit button  limit for A Visitor  using php cookie.
example: if a user sent 3 mail from a php mail form. after 3 mail sent it will display Your limit  is over. how can I do that?

```
<form action="post.php" mathord="post"><input type="email" placeholder="Your Email" name"email"><input type="text" placeholder="Your Text"  name="text"><input type="submit" value="sent" name="sub"></form>
```

after sent mail. if the user try to sent another  email. it will say you already  sent a mail to us

Comment: What have you tried so far ?  Post your code.

Comment: please when every your asking a question try to add a sample code, else no one will fully understand what your asking for except if the question does not need a code

Comment: I add some code sir

Comment: The only way to keep this from being circumvented is to force user to login and then increment a counter in the DB or file related to that user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a completely example of a working form where an IP can only post three times. It's being managed by a JSON "database" and an array.

I hope this helps.

**Code**

```
<?php

if (isset($_POST['sub'])) { // Checking if there's a submit

    $dir = __DIR__ . "/submitted.json"; // File directory

    if (!file_exists($dir)) { // If the file doesn't exist
        file_put_contents($dir, "[]"); // Creates a file
        $jsonDatabase = array();
    } else
        $jsonDatabase = json_decode(file_get_contents($dir), true); // If it exists, it gets the content

    $userIP = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']; // Save the user IP in a variable

    if (array_key_exists($userIP, $jsonDatabase)) { // If the user IP exists in the array

        if ($jsonDatabase[$userIP] <= 3) { // If the IP has less than three submits
            $jsonDatabase[$userIP] += 1; // Adds a submit to the IP
            $canSubmit = true;
        }


    } else { // If the IP doesn't exist in the array
        $jsonDatabase[$userIP] = 1; // Save the IP in the array with the value one
        $canSubmit = true;
    }

    file_put_contents($dir, json_encode($jsonDatabase)); // Save the array back to the "database"

    if ($canSubmit) { // If the IP can submit
        // Do your stuff with the data you've got.
    } else { // If not
        echo "You've reached the limit.";
    }
}

?>

<html>
<head>
    <title>StackOverflow example</title>
</head>
<body>
<form action="index.php" method="post">
    <input type="email" placeholder="Your Email" name="email"/><br>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Your Text" name="text"/><br/>
    <input type="submit" value="Send" name="sub"/>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Regards.

Comment: @AbraCadaver Oh, I can see.. I'm going to make another system right now. Sorry for this, it's late..

Comment: @AbraCadaver Do you like this version? You this it's useful? Regards.

Comment: @RussellRex it's created when this -> `file_put_contents($dir, json_encode($jsonDatabase));` is successfully done. Regards

Comment: I can not understand  sir. can you please  give me complete  clear code. I've been trying for two days, but I can't  solve it